# React POST request, how to reconcile a timing error?

Tags: reactjs, express, post, state

I have a react file tied to an express/node backend and SQL database. My backend is functioning correctly, all routes are verified with postman and the app has the ability to get, post, update, and delete. However, I am running into an issue with my front end now, specifically regarding my POST request.

Every time I make a post request the server/database are being updated correctly with the new applicant, which I can see populate the back end, but I am receiving the following error on the front end **"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'store')" pertaining to my function labeled "TableList"**

Somehow the TableList function which has the role of extrapolating only the unique stores that applicants are assigned too is picking up an "undefined" value for the new store assignment whenever a POST request is made. What is most confusing to me is that if I then reload the page manually the front end displays correctly. Is this a timing issue related to async?

Below is my main file where all state is held - relevant functions are TableList and those containing the markup New Vehicle Form

```
import { useState, useEffect, useImperativeHandle } from "react";
import useFetch from "../Components/Fetch/fetch";
import List from "../Components/Sections/list";
import Intro from "../Components/Sections/intro";
import SearchForm from "../Components/Forms/searchForm";
import AddForm from "../Components/Forms/addForm";
import UpdateForm from "../Components/Forms/updateForm";
import { parseDate } from "../Components/Utils/index";


const Home = () => {

  /* DATE & TIME FORMAT */
  var today = new Date();
  const displaytime = parseDate(today);

  /*INITIAL STATE*/
  const { data, setData, isPending } = useFetch(
    `http://localhost:5000/api/applicants`
  );


  /*NEW VEHICLE FORM: TOGGLE FORM DISPLAY*/
  const [showAddForm, setShowAddForm] = useState(false);

  const handleAddForm = () => {
    setShowAddForm(!showAddForm);
  };

  /*NEW VEHICLE FORM: POST REQUEST, DECLARING STATE*/
  const initialFormState = {
    store: "",
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    position: "",
    recruiterscreen_status:"",
    testing_status:"",
    interview_status:"",
    backgroundcheck_status:"",
    drugscreen_status:"",
    paperwork_status:"",
    date_in: "",
    currentdate: displaytime,
    notes:"",
  };

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ ...initialFormState });

  /*NEW VEHICLE FORM: POST REQUEST, UPDATING STATE*/
  const handleFormChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  /*NEW VEHICLE FORM: POST REQUEST, TRIGGER RERENDER*/
  const confirmpost = (applicant) => {
    setData([...data, applicant])
    console.log(data)
  };

  /*NEW VEHICLE FORM: POST REQUEST, SUBMIT TO SERVER*/
  const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const applicant = formData;
    console.log(applicant);
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/applicants/`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(applicant),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => console.log("Added Successfully"))
      .then((applicant) => confirmpost(applicant))
      .then(()=>handleAddForm())
      .catch((error) => console.log("Form submit error", error));

    setFormData({ ...initialFormState });
  };

  
  

  /*DELETE APPLICANT: FRONT END RERENDER*/
  const deleteApplicant = (id) => {
    const updatedTable = data.filter((item) => item.applicant_id != id);
    setData(updatedTable);
  };

  /*DELETE APPLICANT: SERVER REQUEST*/
  const handleDelete = (id, stock) => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/applicants/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    })
      .then((response) => console.log("Deleted Applicant"))
      .then(() => deleteApplicant(id));
  };
  

   /*UPDATE FORM: TOGGLE FORM DISPLAY, ALSO GRAB USER ID*/
   const [showUpdateForm, setShowUpdateForm] = useState(false);
   const [selectedApplicant, setSelectedApplicant] = useState(null)
   const [selectedApplicantName, setSelectedApplicantName] = useState(null)
 
   const handleUpdateForm = (applicant_id, first_name,last_name) => {
     setSelectedApplicant(applicant_id)
     setSelectedApplicantName(first_name + " "+ last_name)
     setShowUpdateForm(!showUpdateForm);
     console.log(`Show Form: ${showUpdateForm}`)
   };

  /*UPDATE FORM: DECLARE INITIAL STATE*/
  const initialStatusState = {
    recruiterscreen_status:null,
    testing_status: null,
    interview_status:null,
    backgroundcheck_status: null,
    drugscreen_status: null,
    paperwork_status:null,
    notes:null,
  };

  /*UPDATE FROM: CHANGE APPLICANT STATE*/
  const [statusData, setStatusData] = useState({ ...initialStatusState });

  const handleStatusChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setStatusData({
      ...statusData,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

 
  
  /*UPDATE FORM: SUMBIT TO SERVER*/
  const handleUpdate = (id) => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/applicants/${id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(statusData),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(() => confirmUpdate(id))
      .then((response) => console.log(`Updated Successfully to 
      recruiterscreen_status: ${statusData.recruiterscreen_status},
      testing_status: ${statusData.testing_status},
      interview_status: ${statusData.interview_status},
      backgroundcheck_status: ${statusData.backgroundcheck_status},
      drugscreen_status: ${statusData.drugscreen_status},
      paperwork_status: ${statusData.paperwork_status},
      notes:${statusData.notes},`));
  
    setStatusData({ ...initialStatusState });
  };

  /*UPDATE FORM: FRONT END RERENDER*/
  const confirmUpdate = (id) => {
    const updatedTable = data.map((item) =>
      item.applicant_id != id
        ? item
        : {
            ...item,
            recruiterscreen_status: statusData.recruiterscreen_status,
            testing_status: statusData.testing_status,
            interview_status: statusData.interview_status,
            backgroundcheck_status: statusData.backgroundcheck_status,
            drugscreen_status: statusData.drugscreen_status,
            paperwork_status: statusData.paperwork_status,
            notes:statusData.notes,
          }
    );
    setData(updatedTable);
    handleUpdateForm(id)
  };


/* NOTES POP UP */
 const [notesIsOpen, setNotesIsOpen] = useState(false)

 const togglePopup = () => {
   setNotesIsOpen(!notesIsOpen)
 }


   /*LIST OF ACTIVE STORES*/

   const unique = (value, index, self) => {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  };
  
    const TableList = (data) => {
      const list = data.map((element) => element.store);
      const uniquelist = list.filter(unique).sort();
      console.log(uniquelist)
      return uniquelist;
    };
    
    const stores = TableList(data)
    





  /*RUN*/

  return (
    <div>
      
      <Intro displaytime={displaytime} />

      <div className="add-applicant">
        <button className="add-applicant-btn" onClick={handleAddForm}>
          Add Applicant
        </button>
      </div>
      <SearchForm data={data} setData={setData} />

      {showAddForm ? (
        <AddForm
          formData={formData}
          setFormData={setFormData}
          handleFormChange={handleFormChange}
          handleFormSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
        />
      ) : null}

      
      {showUpdateForm ? (
        <UpdateForm data={data} selectedApplicant={selectedApplicant} selectedApplicantName={selectedApplicantName} handleUpdateForm={handleUpdateForm} statusData={statusData} handleStatusChange={handleStatusChange} handleUpdate={handleUpdate} />
      ) : null}


      <hr></hr>

      {!isPending ?  (
     
        stores.map((element) => (
          <div>
            {" "}
            <List
             cut={element}
              data={data}
              isPending={isPending}
              handleDelete={handleDelete}
              handleUpdate={handleUpdate}
              handleStatusChange={handleStatusChange}
              showUpdateForm={showUpdateForm}
              handleUpdateForm={handleUpdateForm}
              togglePopup={togglePopup}
              notesIsOpen={notesIsOpen}
              TableList={TableList}
            />
         </div>
        ))
      ) : (
        <div>Loading</div>
      )}
    </div>
      );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Your "then" handler with the console log returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In the `fetch` chain the logging step which injects an `undefined` into the chain.

The logging step needs to pass on its input data:

```js
fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/applicants/`, { }) // Elided
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("Added Successfully")
    return response
  )
  .then((applicant) => confirmpost(applicant))
```